# Check if my AWS Application load Balancer is forwarding the requests to the correct target groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, target, aws-application-load-balancer

Is there a way that would allow me to check if my ALB is respecting the target rules ?

**Input**:
ALB
URL1 -> (should be forwarded to ) TG1
URL2 -> ("""""""""""""""""""""" ) TG2

**Output**:
ALB works correctly or not.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable [Access logs for your Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html) to check if the requests are being forwarded.

OR

Enable [VPC Flow Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html)

[Monitor your Application Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-monitoring.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking the backend logs be it a lambda function or EC2 instances.

In case of EC2 instances, try to keep the number of instances associated with the target group equals to 1 instance, otherwise, you need to monitor all instances at the same time to ensure no requests are dropped.

From within the instance, go to the web server log file (nginx, apache, tomcat...) and tail the file with a follow option
"tail -f {web_server_log_file_name}"

If you doubt your request is reaching the load balancer at all, you can set the load balancer rule to return a fixed response and try to send a request to check if that fixed response is the one being sent back to you.